# I have a form that I want to hide some textfields until one option y selected on a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown with 3 options option1, option2 and option3 then I have 3 text fields for each option, I want the text fields to be hidden until 1 option is selected then I want to show only those 3 fields.

I have been searching and trying a lot of javascript functions but they are not working at all or they only show 1 of the text fields but they don't hide back if they switch option.

I gave up and ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try jQuery. Start by wrapping your fields within divs, (each se group of textboxes in each div)
use this to hide them

CSS

```
}
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

then use this function

jQuery

```
$(function(){
$("select[name='option1']").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "value1"){
        $("div[name='group1']").show();
        $("div[name='group2']").hide();
        $("div[name='group3']").hide();
    }
});
```

and your form elements should be something like this

HTML

```
<select name="option1" id="option1">
<option value="value1">value</option>
<option value="value2">value</option>
<option value="value3">value</option>
</select>

<div id="group1" name="group1" class="hidden" style="display: block; ">
<label>text:</label>
<input type="text" name="text1"><br><br>
<label>text:</label>
<input type="text" name="text2"><br><br>
<label>text:</label>
<input type="text" name="text3">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this one actually worked like I wanted. I tried the first one and it worked so I guess the other 2 are just rinse and repeat?

Comment: Yes just make sure you select the ones you want to hide and the one to show.

Answer (score 0):

Put a class on the select and input tags

```
<select class="opts">...</select>
// Other select tags
<input class="inputs" style="display: none; " ...>
// Other input tags

// Somewhere in a script tag
$('.opts').on('change', function() {
  $('.inputs').show()
  $('.opts').hide()
});
```